# Virtualbox Drag N Drop isn't working

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox, drag-and-drop

I followed the steps but still can't drag and drop files to Virtualbox guest OS.  I went to Settings, General, Advanced, clicked Bidirectional on both Shared Clipboard and Drag N Drop and i still can't drag or copy anything to the guest OS(Win7). Am i missing something?

Comment: drag'n'drop support feature requires the installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions. Make sure you don't install the Guest Additions package available in the official Ubuntu repository ("virtualbox-guest-additions") and instead, install the Guest Additions from the VirtualBox menu (Devices > Install Guest Additions).

Comment: I just tried it and I have linux on the guest and host and I draged the folder out the guest to the hosts folder and the folder disappeared from the guest and didn't appear in the host folder so where is the folder..??

Answer (score 7):

## EDIT

Now drag and drop is no more experimental in Virtualbox. To make it working, follow the official instructions:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/DnDDebug

---

## Original Post

Drag and Drop works only for Linux guests (guest: OS on the virtual machine)

[Changelog for VirtualBox 4.2.0](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/virtualbox-420-released-with-support.html#more):

> Added experimental support for Drag'n'drop from the host to Linux guests. Support for more guests and for guest-to-host is planned.

As guitar42697 said, you have to set a shared folder.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question and it's asking about doing the reverse (host is Linux, guest is Windows) but I hope this will help others like myself set up drag'n'drop where the host is Windows and guest is Linux.

In the VirtualBox window with the VM, click *Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD image...*

[image: Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD image...]

It will appear as a mounted CD in the Linux host OS. Follow the steps to install it, then reboot the VM.

Then enable Drag'n'Drop with *Devices > Drag'n'Drop > Bidirectional*

[image: Devices > Drag'n'Drop > Bidirectional]
(you can also choose another option if you don't want bidirectional drag'n'drop)

You may also want to enable Shared Clipboards with Devices > Shared Clipboard > Bidirectional.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must set up a shared folder, so you can drag things from ubuntu, into the folder, and it will appear in Windows 7, and vice versa. as far as I know, you cannot directly drag and drop items into virtualbox

Comment: Your right.  I viewed the YouTube video and followed the instructions.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5f1p3fZJPc  It worked.  Thx

Answer (score 1):

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 guest running under Windows 7, and it happens to me quite a bit, that a shared folder will "suddenly" be "empty" (and/or unaccessible) when viewed from the guest (/media/sf_vmShare).  I believe this happens when Ubuntu updates itself, sometimes.  The solution is to re-install the Guest Additions, as per the instruction already posted and reboot the guest.

Comment: It worked for me after re-installing Guest Additions to enable Drag N Drop from Windows 10 (Guest) to Ubuntu 20.04 (Host)