# Why my Guest Additions ISO file wont run in ubuntu virtualbox running in windows 11?

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, guest-additions, cd-image

I am using virtual machine on windows 11 laptop and guest is running latest Ubuntu version with minimal install.

I am trying to install Guest Additions. I get to the point where "cd" and its content are visible, but it simply wont run. All other tutorials show that it would prompt run automatically. For me it will not give me prompt even if I try it manually. [Here is demonstration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4in4.jpg) I tried multiple things already including starting from scratch, but nothing seems to work. Yesterday I did it with Linux Mint and it worked. Previously I've done this on my desktop pc with Ubuntu.

PS. I'm not sure, but maybe the minimal install does not install some particular tool that is required for this to work. That is the only thing that comes to my mind when comparing to other successful installs.

EDIT:
Here is output of what first comment suggested:
[image]

EDIT 2:
I tried this also with full ubuntu installation so my assumption on PS. probably does not aply.

Comment: Open a terminal within that folder and run the command `sudo ./autorun.sh`. If that does not work, try `sudo ./runasroot.sh`.

Comment: I edited the post and pasted output of these commands.

Comment: Ok. Try the following. First enter the command `su` and enter your password. Then enter the command `./runasroot.sh`

Comment: Thanks, but sadly gives me exactly the same output. Though it is contradicting that when I run it with as superuser it still suggests me trying it.

Comment: Ok. Let's wait for someone else to address this issue. Meanwhile, please ensure that you are running the latest version of virtualbox.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Virtual box says it is running Version 6.1.36 r152435 (Qt5.6.2). Witch seems to be the latest version as far as I can tell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" on 'Open in Terminal' (Ubuntu 22.04LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407041/failed-to-execute-child-process-dbus-launch-on-open-in-terminal-ubuntu-22-0)

Comment: @user535733 To be honest I don't understand any of that. Should I type some spesific command in terminal after installing dbus? I am very noob in everything ubuntu/linux related that does not use graphical user interface (not that good at that either).

Comment: @user535733 Ok. Thanks for feedback. Sorry, wasn't trying to be rude. After you commented I edited the post. Problem persists even when trying it in full Ubuntu install. I was trying to spare resourses with minimal install, since this is not high end laptop and I still plan to use windows alongside it. Probably not the best choice, but trial and error and all that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. All I had to do was right click `autorun.sh` and choose `Run as a program`. After that terminal opened asking for sudo privileges. This worked both on minimal and full Ubuntu installs.

[Right click menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQCbT.png)

Comment: Guest additions are also in the repositories. You could just have installed them with `apt`.

Comment: Yes, it works and copy and paste works too but dragging files between the main and the virtual doesn't work. Something for repare this?

Comment: @JSERRANO File dragging is something actually I have not tried out at all. I would figure guest additions is installed correctly since you are able to copy and paste. On this question  https://askubuntu.com/questions/333616/virtualbox-drag-n-drop-isnt-working first comment Nim suggests that you get different "versions" depending on where you download it from. I'm not sure if that is helpful at all and take it with grain of salt, because this is not at all my expertise (this is just a guess).